# Proper syntax to assign std::vector to a specific memory location on the heap?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, stl

I am trying to implement the directions in these two SO posts regarding assigning containers to specific memory locations on the heap:

1. [Moving C++ objects, especially stl containers, to a specific memory location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244010/moving-c-objects-especially-stl-containers-to-a-specific-memory-location)
2. [Create objects in pre-allocated memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301043/create-objects-in-pre-allocated-memory)

However, I must be doing something stupid (I'm new to C++) because I can't even get my code to compile (using C++ 11 as you can see below):

```
  std::vector<int> ints1 = {10, 20, 30};
  ints1.reserve(20);
  auto adr = &(*ints1.end());
  auto *ints2 = new(adr)(std::vector<int>(20);
```

I am getting an error of a `expected , or ; before )` for the last line, which I take to mean that my syntax is just wrong, but how?

Also, once I fix this syntax, what's the best way to ensure these objects really are contiguous? I thought I would ensure that

```
&(*ints1.begin()) - &(*ints2.begin) is roughly on the order of sizeof(std::vector<int> v(20));
```

Is there a better way?

(p.s. I do realize I should allocate the memory I am going to use to do this to avoid undefined behavior)

Comment: Creating a *vector* at a specific memory location will not affect where its data is stored because internally it contains only a pointer to its data.

Comment: Why do you want to have two different `std::vector` variables contiguous? `std::vector` already guarantees that elements are allocated in contiguous memory.

Comment: If this is remotely intended to manage *elements* in a predefined area of memory, this code isn't even close. You need a custom *allocator* as the first linked question indicates.

Comment: `ints1.end()` may be a singular value, not necessarily a past-the-end pointer. You should use `&ints1[0] + 3` or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a ) before ;. Should look like this

```
 auto *ints2 = new(adr)(std::vector<int>(20));
```